# MVC 4 App with Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, basic-authentication, iis-8

I'm getting an error with an application that's using basic authentication for IIS 8. When I start the application it takes too long to run and also it doesn't load the .js and .css files.
The weirdest thing is that the same application loads correctly in other 3 machines but mine.
I defined an Application Pool with my network credentials and on Basic Authentication I also defined the host.
In my MVC project, on Web tab the project url is something like "http://localhost/MyAppName".
Is there anything that I could do to solve this?

Comment: Check your application pool is running in `Integrated` and .Net Framework  it's on `V4.0...`, if you don't see the .Net Framework v4.0, reinstall or try also `aspnet_regiis` Tool.

Comment: Did you end up finding solution?

Comment: @mijail yes, I checked and everything is right!

Comment: @CrnaStena, what do you thing? I think maybe some features are missing on the IIS8. Deise Vicentin, Did you enabled .net3.5, .net4,  and basic authentication on windows features under IIS?

Comment: @DeiseVicentin, also UrlRewrite feature, maybe these one is missing

Comment: @mijail I think setting up environment can be painful some days and debugging via SO does not always work, because of untold number of configuration possibilities.

Comment: Well, I ended up with no solution. My co-workers suggested me to format my notebook, so I did that and now it's working. Thank you for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to load .js and .css is usually the case when your application pool is running in `Classic` mode. Try switching it to `Integrated`. Also, make sure your pool is running v4.0 .NET Framework.

Comment: No, it's running in Integrated mode. I checked again.